# Positioning on top of a input text field?

Tags: html, css

I want to position `.select-delete` on top of the `<input>` text field. I did this once before, but alas I lost the code, and I'm pretty sure the surrounding elements CSS properties were different.

Here's a link to my JS fiddle, so that you can edit/see what I'm talking about: http://jsfiddle.net/gPF8X/

I've tried a negative `margin-top` but it's sent to the back of and hidden behind the text field. I've also tried to set `float` which alone with altering `margin` settings, which had the same effect.

Any edits/answers that have the desired effect would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/gPF8X/2/

Like this:

I set the position of the #box to relative.

then set the position of the .select-delete box to absolute

CSS

```
#box {
    margin: 20px auto 20px;
    background: #fff;
    width: 460px;
    padding: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    color: #444;
    position:relative;
}
.select-delete {
    margin-left: 430px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    background: url(http://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/aspneticons_v1.0_Nov2006/delete_16x16.gif) no-repeat;
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    position:absolute;
    top:40px;

}
```

Comment: Also if you are going to have multiple instance of this you may want to wrap your inputs in <label> tags and set those to position:relative and position the "x"'s accordingly. inside of those.